# How to check index creation progress in MongoDB via shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

On a large collection of billions records in MongoDB an index creation is submitted.
I run `db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate([ { "$indexStats": { } } ] )` and i get result containing property `building:true`.

**Question:** How could I check the progress of the index building e.g. percentage complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db.currentOp` https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/currentOp/

It returns a lot, but you are interested in a document where `command` has `createIndexes` or `msg`  string contains "Index Build".

If the output is too noisy, you can filter running adminCommand directly:

```
db.adminCommand(
    {
      currentOp: true,
      $or: [
        { op: "command", "command.createIndexes": { $exists: true }  },
        { op: "none", "msg" : /^Index Build/ }
      ]
    }
)
```

The field `progress` of the document reveals `done` and `total`. You can do the math.